# Dovecot QuotaClone plugin

Tags: dovecot, quota

I am trying to get the new [QuotaClone plugin](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Plugins/QuotaClone) in Dovecot (2.2.18) working. The documentation says the configuration should be like this:

```
mail_plugins = $mail_plugins quota quota_clone
plugin {
  quota_clone_dict = redis:127.0.0.1:6379
}
```

However, it does not say anything about the configuration file this should be in, so I assumed 20-lmtp.conf and 90-quota.conf are
the appropriate locations. The Dovecot example immediately returned the following error "Error: quota_clone_dict: Failed to initialize 'redis:127.0.0.1:6379': dict redis: Unknown parameter: 6379".

After looking at the [plugin code](http://hg.dovecot.org/dovecot-2.2/file/f17065f4f9f2/src/plugins/quota-clone/quota-clone-plugin.c) and the [redis dict code](http://hg.dovecot.org/dovecot-2.2/file/f17065f4f9f2/src/lib-dict/dict-redis.c), I changed it to the configuration below. It does not return any error now, but it does not work either (tcpdump shows no packages going to Redis).

90-quota.conf

```
plugin {
  quota = maildir:User quota
  quota_clone_dict = redis:host=127.0.0.1:port=6379
}
```

20-lmtp.conf

```
protocol lmtp {
  postmaster_address = postmaster@company.com
  mail_plugins = $mail_plugins quota quota_clone
}
```

I know the Quota Clone plugin is quite new, but maybe someone got it working already and can share some knowledge with me?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with mysql and quota_clone_dict. Any news here?

Comment: Possible explanation: *"quota_clone does not do anything unless quota is doing something"* as [answered here](https://serverfault.com/a/774771/250204).

Answer (score -1):

Redis server should be described as

`quota_clone_dict = redis:127.0.0.1:6379`

Comment: As stated in my post, that returns an error. Besides that, there is a difference between the docs and the actual code.

Comment: So you have to dig into code, sorry.