# Dovecot quota clone

Tags: mysql, dovecot, quota, clone

I'm trying to use dovecot's quotas and share them via mysql with modoboa.
I'm using the count module for that:

http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Quota/Count

To share the quota I'm trying to implement the new clone option:

http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Plugins/QuotaClone

I now have a configuration that doesn't throw any errors in the logs but the mysql database remains empty

This is my `dovecot.conf`:

```
service dict {
  unix_listener dict {
  }
}

dict {
  sqlquota = mysql:/usr/local/etc/dovecot/dovecot-dict-sql.conf
}

plugin {
    […]        
    quota = count:User quota
    #quota_rule = *:storage=5G
    quota_grace = 20%%
    quota_vsizes = yes
    quota_clone_dict = proxy::sqlquota
    […]
}
```

This is my 'dovecot-dict-sql.conf':

```
connect = ***********
map {
  pattern = priv/quota/storage
  table = admin_quota
  username_field = username
  value_field = bytes
}
map {
  pattern = priv/quota/messages
  table = admin_quota
  username_field = username
  value_field = messages
}
```

What would be the right method to implement the new quota clone plugin?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same problem,

To work quota_clone_dict, you need to define quota_rule

Even quota_rule with unlimited quota will not work here

UN-Comment below line in your dovecot.conf.

`#quota_rule = *:storage=5G`